# How can I determine which request is lazy-loading a particular section of a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

**What I am doing**:

Scraping Amazon products such as https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B000F5NNKE.

**Problem:**

The scraper starts out fine and the pages load fully for a while. However, Amazon eventually figures out I am scraping it and, instead of blocking me, the source code it sends back as a response no longer contains the two sections in the image below, namely **"Descrição do produto"** (in black) and **"Informações sobre o produto"** (below, in orange)

[image: "Descrição do produto" and "Informações sobre o produto" are both missing]

**What I need:**

Changing agents and proxies only works for a while so ideally what I wanted was a way to send a request to a specific URL so that I can request these sections directly instead of trying to make Amazon include them in the source code.

**What I have tried:**

I have looked at the XHR tab in the Network tab of developer tools but the requests were indecipherable to me.

**QUESTION**

Is there another a way I can figure out exactly which request loads these sections so that I don't need to use something more drastic like Javascript rendering?

Comment: In Chrome's inspector, you can search text over all loaded scripts. You could try that and find out which request contains information you need specifically. However, rendering Javascript is actually safer in terms of bot detection, because it's even more obvious that you're a robot if you can request a specific AJAX call without rendering Javascript to load other resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying! I tried searching for fragments of the product description in the response tab but I couldn't find anything, unfortunately. Is there something else I could try? Perhaps a way to approve these requests one by one before they are loaded to see which one actually loads the content? As for Amazon knowing I am a bot, as long as I have this link it should be fine, I think, because I have successfully done this in the past to display a prices section. All I needed was a cookie and the link and it returns the AJAX loaded page without disrupting the connection in any way

Comment: It seems those two sections in your image are not loaded by javascript AJAX. It's inside the HTML plain-text of your link.

Comment: So it's just something internal that decides which source code version to send? If so, then rendering JavaScript, wouldn't help, and I could try would be to use multiple proxies and spread out the requests, right? What do you recommend?

Comment: Agree. You can try with simple `requests` get call, with proxies or scrapping service. But again, sometimes javascript rendering helps you get away with bot detection